# Adding a Sub Folder Reader to python script

Tags: python

I have been researching and trying thing to make this script read through folders and subfolders

```
import glob
import os

for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    new_filename = f.replace("(Fence)","(Gates)")
    new_filename = new_filename
    os.rename(f,new_filename)
```

I have tried for f in `os.walk('.'):` I think I have it right, but I do get an error, not sure how to fix

the code up top works fine, but once I add `os.walk` it gives an error 
No more error

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        nmin = os.path.join(root,name)
new_filename = nmin.replace("Fence","Gates")
new_filename = nmin.replace("House","Homes")
        new_filename = new_filename
        os.rename(nmin,new_filename)
```

What am I missing 
The CMD loads up, but nothing happens

any help will be great

Comment: Read about `os.walk` to understand how to use it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: You should use `pathlib` instead of `os`

Comment: @Jeremy - I'm testing the os.walk more, this time I have no error, but still nothing happens